# Android custom Progress Dialog webview

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, spinner

I am currently using ProgressDialog for my webivew. Like this below:

How can i make only the spinner visible and not the dialog box, and center the spinner ?

```
 pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
         true);

 Webf = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebFaceId);
 Webf.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         if(pd.isShowing() && pd!=null)
         {
         pd.dismiss();
         }
     }


     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
            v.loadUrl(url);


            return true;


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Indeterminate ProgressBar to your layout xml. Use the proper attributes to put it where ever you like. Set it to visibility="gone". Instead of pd.show() use progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);, and View.GONE, when you want to hide it again.